# Accessing the key type in a mapped type

Tags: typescript

I have a mapped type like this:

```js
type Mapped = { [Key in string]: Key };
```

Which, to my understanding, should only allow types where the key is identical to the value. However, both the following cases are allowed:

```js
function mapped<const T extends Mapped>(t: T): T {
    return t;
}

// this should be the only allowed case
const mapped1 = mapped({
    'foo': 'foo ',
});

// should not be allowed
const mapped2 = mapped({
    'foo': 'bar',
});
```

Is there a way to ensure that the desired constraint is being respected? Also, please note that the end goal is to allow the `Mapped` objects to be recursively nested into one another, so using a generic type parameter is difficult, since type parameters are very difficult (and often impossible) to use with recursive types. The final type will look something like this:

```js
type Mapped = { 
    [Key in string]: {
        fn: (key: Key) => void,
        children: Mapped
    } 
};
```

It is paramount, that the parameter of `fn` is always properly typed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enforce the constraint that the key and value must be identical, you can modify the Mapped type as follows:

```
type Mapped<T extends string> = { [Key in T]: Key };
```

With this modification, you need to provide a type parameter T when using the Mapped type. The type parameter T specifies the allowed keys in the Mapped type. The values will then be restricted to be the same as the keys. Here's how you can use it:

```
function mapped<T extends string>(t: Mapped<T>): Mapped<T> {
    return t;
}

// Allowed because the key and value are identical
const mapped1 = mapped({
    'foo': 'foo',
});

// Not allowed because the key and value are different
const mapped2 = mapped({
    'foo': 'bar',
});
```